# Facebook Icon/Button Glowing in iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook, uinavigationbar

Does anyone know/have a guess as to how facebook implemented the glowing of the icon when a user taps the icon? (You can see what I mean below) It seems to me that they implemented at least part of it programmatically as the glowing actually spills over on the icon next to it. Has anyone done this or have pointers where to start? It does not seem to spill out of the UINavigationBar, however.

[image: Facebook Icon Glowing]

PS. I do know how to make the icons up on the navigation bar, just not sure how to implement the glowing...

Comment: Looks to me like it could be as simple as they've told the (likely) UIButton with it's image set as the globe icon not to clipToBounds (so it bleeds over) and added a shadow that's white. They've also possibly made it the front subView so it definitely flows over the other icon(s).

Comment: Isn't this just the property of the UIButton class called showsTouchWhenHighlighted, or does that look different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIButton` has a property called `showsTouchWhenHighlighted`. When you set this to true, it puts that glow whenever you tap it.

For some reason it goes behind the icon when you use it as a custom view of a `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UIToolbar` or a `UINavigationBar` (contrary to if you simply set the image of the `UIBarButtonItem`).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It is indeed the correct answer and has saved me a lot of hassle! Also, there's a checkbox to set the property in Interface Builder so there's no need to do it in your code (unless you're creating the button programmatically, of course).